# Highly upvoted comments silently removed?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-comments

I have this answer that I made 6 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666418. This answer has some perhaps unusually looking illustrations, which many people liked a lot.

6 years ago, someone asked in comment to this answer how to create such illustrations, to which I answered how exactly to do that: create pictures in PowerPoint or Libre Office Impress and then attach them to stackoverflow post. This comment itself received at least 20 upvotes over the years.

However, about month ago, both original comment asking for illustrations and my answer have been silently removed, simply disappeared.

I wonder why? I believe it should be difficult to remove highly upvoted comments even for moderators. At least original commenters should be notified of this action.

Comment: I agree with that the original commenter must be notified but not with the case that it must be difficult for mods to delete them. Irrelevant comments to posts which are of no use or are or different topic then the post ought to be removed.

Comment: Comments are not meant to be for ever lasting and should primarily be used to ask for clarification / point out issues with the post. Comments that are not contributing to that goal are open for no longer needed flags. While there might be some hesitation to remove upvoted comments by no means that should make comments ineligible for deletion. Given the many comments that are deleted, notifying the posters will only lead to similar meta posts like this very one where I foresee heated debates without an outcome that will improve the content we curate for.

Comment: I understand. I am with @rene

Comment: @Lighteninger please upvote my comment so it can no longer be removed by moderators ;)

Comment: @rene ***Drat***. You foiled me this time, rene, but you *won't get away with it* next time! *evil laugh*.

Comment: I understand why heated or controversial comments should be deleted. But what's the point of deleting constructive comments? Especially if they were deemed adding value by many readers? It's like eroding knowledge base that stackoverflow is.

Comment: deleted comment which reads "+1 for the nice illustration" was upvoted 33 times...

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisSabre: exactly. but then it actually asked how to do such illustrations. Why would anyone want to delete such comment?

Comment: Actually, after I raised it, almost all comments are now deleted. Really???

Comment: that's the meta effect...

Comment: @mvp They got removed simply because it does not have anything to do with the actual answer, which is reasonable. It's fine to ask such questions in comments, and also to answer them, but don't count on them staying there forever.

Comment: @klutt, they did have something to do with the answer. BTW, now comments are removed even from all other answers. War on comments in full effect - I have not seen anything like that ever before, and this is very disconcerting.

Comment: @mvp Asking how you made the images in the answer does not have anything to with the answer itself. At least not in any way that is relevant. I'm not saying that I'm not enjoying reading such comments, because I do. But they are off target. And what you are witnessing is the meta effect. People are flagging your comments now. While I don't condone that sort of actions, it's pretty harmless in this case since it's only comments. It's a lot worse when it comes to serial down voting.

Comment: @klutt, in this case it came down to serial removing of all comments in all of my answers. It's another kind of digital bullying. I don't feel like Stackoverflow is welcoming place it used to be. If people are asking how to make such illustrations here on Stackoverflow, it doesn't mean they belong to sites like Superuser. It is core of what Stackoverflow is.

Comment: @mvp I did say I don't condone it, didn't I? Was just stating that it's not as bad as one alternative. You are correct that SO is not as welcoming as it has been, but on the other hand, that would not work because SO has grown to big. Compare it to the IRC channels in the past. The small channels needed extremely little or no moderation. But channels that had hundreds of users required pretty heavy moderation. I would not consider it wrong if a moderator decided not to remove your comment, but I do consider it wrong to *expect* them to do so. After all, they ARE intended to be temporary.

Comment: @mvp For the same reason that you should not store things you want to keep in a ram disk on a shared computer and hope that no one turns of the power, you should not put things in a comment that you want to be permanent. And one solution you could have chosen (I have done like that myself) is to create a new self answered question, either on SO or SU, whichever is more appropriate, and then add a line in the answer saying. "People were asking how I made these pictures. You can read about it here: <link/to/question>

Comment: @klutt, again, it's not about one particular comment. It's about bullying - I don't feel welcomed here anymore, I don't feel safe making comments. Anything I say can and does disappear without any trace, including this very comment. Many of my answers are now being cleared of all and any comments. I didn't experience this in many years contributing to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @mvp And as I said twice, I don't condone it. But on the other hand I think it is good in general to clean up comments. The only bad thing here is that you are targeted. But yes, you are completely correct that your comments can disappear at any time. Because they are *explicitly intended to be temporary*. If you want what you say to be permanent, don't post it in a comment. And again. SO has changed to be able to cope with the massive number of users nowadays.

Comment: @klutt, my simple answer to this bullying is simply to stop contributing. For many years, these comments didn't bother anyone. In just one day, most of my comments I made over these years are gone. I understand that I could have converted them into separate answers, but who has time for that? 99% of other popular answers have lots of comments, and no one seems to be clearing them. My answer is screw it, I don't care anymore.

Comment: @mvp Sorry to hear it. I think the biggest problem here is unreasonable expectations from you. You seem to be one of those that want everything to remain the way they were. I'm like that too. I'm very nostalgic. But it is completely unreasonable to expect SO to not adjust to new situations. Yes, it worked before, but it does not work very well now. If 99% of other answers has a lot of comments, well then something should be done about that.

Comment: @mvp Also, you're saying that you "don't have time" to convert them into answers. Well, do you think the moderators have time to carefully look at every individual comment to decide if it should be kept albeit not being relevant to the post? And if the moderator did decide to keep it, how would we prevent the next moderator from deleting it? There are technical solutions to this, like introducing new rules about the comments, and maybe require three deletion votes for comments. But that would take time and energy from stuff that is far more important.

Comment: @klutt, they obviously found time to remove ALL of my comments that I made over the years, overnight. And not only on this answer, many others as well. If this is not bullying, I don't know what is.

Comment: @mvp Most likely because other users flagged them. The moderators just see a queue with flagged comments and go through the queue the same way we do with the review queues. And for the last time. I agree that this is bullying, and I do NOT condone it. Apart from the bullying aspect, I recommend you to take a step back and try to look at this matter from different perspectives.

Comment: @klutt, and now we're back to my original question: why first moderator even agreed to delete comment with 33 upvotes? I don't believe such decision should be taken lightly. Perhaps we should have moderators also have automated review sanity check like we, mere mortals used to have?

Comment: @mvp I think you're taking this far to seriously. I'm done now.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, *any* comment can be removed without warning, at any time. From the [help centre entry on commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are **temporary "Post-It" notes** left on a question or answer.

(bold emphasis mine)

Comments are temporary. Don't rely on them sticking around. The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of great questions and their answers, and comments serve that goal only to make sure the question and answer quality is the best we can make them. Once they have served their purpose, *they are just noise that distract from the goals*.

The same page explains what comments are for:

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

(emphasis in the original)

Comments that have served their purpose or don't fall under those headings can be flagged as *no longer needed*. While moderators do take upvotes into account to understand their context and impact, that doesn't mean they are somehow protected.

Comment upvotes help make them stand out when there are multiple comments on a post, votes on comments have no other value.

> 6 years ago, someone asked in comment to this answer how to create such illustrations, to which I answered how exactly to do that

That's not one of the stated purposes of comments. In the same help centre entry is a section on when *not* to comment, which includes:

> - **Secondary discussion** or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;

How to create illustrations is best left to other sites, such as Super User.

> I believe it should be difficult to remove highly upvoted comments even for moderators.

No, comments that are obsolete or not pertinent to the post are *just noise*, no matter how many votes they got. If a comment contains something valuable to the current question or answer, then the *post should be edited to include that information*. Comments are not meant to be permanent, questions and answers are.

> At least original commenters should be notified of this action.

We delete thousands and thousands of comments every week, you'd be easily overwhelmed. For example, this past week moderators have collectively deleted 7186 comments.

You can't see deleted comments once they are gone, there is no value in notifications like these, and would only lead to confusion when comments are old enough for the original author to have forgotten what they were about.

Don't put anything in comments that you don't want to see deleted.

Comment: And now almost all comments in this answer are deleted. Thanks, moderators. You may as well delete the answer now.

Comment: @mvp Huh? If the comments were vital to the answer, shouldn't they have been added to it? Answers should not depend on comments to be clear.

Comment: @ModusTollens, unfortunately, it doesn't work like that in practice. Read any, and I mean ANY popular answer, it will be full of comments. Should we start a war on deleting all comments? Comments do carry some useful information, even if subtle sometimes. And many answers will lose value without accompanying comments.

Comment: @mvp I agree that it doesn't work like that in practice, but I was reacting to your previous comment. If an answer may as well be deleted as soon as the _comments_  are gone, it implies it is missing vital information that was given in comments.

Comment: @mvp: why would we delete an accepted 800+ answer, because we cleaned up the comments? We regularly do this, also on popular answers. Again, if there is information in the comments that should be part of the answer, put it in the answer. Comments that still appear to fall within the normal usage guidelines won't be deleted, so if you see such posts with a lot of comments, feel free to flag them for moderator attention in bulk.